# GSM 8 bit data encoding

Tags: mobile, sms, gsm

8 bit data encoding mode treats the information as raw data. According to the standard, the alphabet for this encoding is user specific.Please explain more in detail.

Comment: Usually UTF-8 is the way to go. That's how non-Latin SMS texts are sent.

Answer (score 5):

Are you referring to switching a GSM modem into 8 bit binary mode?
Or are you talking about the data coding used within an SMS.

The first (binary mode) is just the connection to the modem allowing it to report the whole SMS in it's raw bytes rather than it trying to decode the SMS as a 7 bit text message. It allows you to get at all the bytes of a message, but if a message is in 7 bit GSM character set, you have to unpack it yourself.

The second (data coding value) is a value on the SMS telling the receiving equipment what data coding the message has been sent in. Refer to GSM 03.38 for it values as it performs various functions depending on the context. But in terms of character sets, it can be set to 7bit GSM character set, UCS2 (which is not UTF-8. It is almost but not quite UTF-16), or 8-bit data. The 8-bit data is used in conjunction with a User Data Header (UDH) to send to an application on the phone (eg. WAP settings or Nokia ringtone).

Answer (score 2):

8-bit data encoding means that you can insert binary data within an SMS. You could also add UTF-8 encoded characters when you so wish.

Normally 8-bit messages are not viewable by mobile phones as text messages.